# Query in Google sheets to select rows whose value didn't change over the last 30 days

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, pivot-table

I have this pivot table in one worksheet, and I want to write a query to select only those rows whose `Logistic` is `US` and whose values didn't change over the past 30 days and write it in another sheet of the same spreadsheet. Here is the [link to the demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13m5BDkCAAsJvWr_gknCCcbRPzeTmVGVuI_3fa29GBiw/edit?usp=sharing) sheet with the pivot table and desired output. In the desired output sheet, I just manually pasted the filtered data by Logistic type US and looked up the EANs with the unchanged quantity for the past 30 days. So, the last date is *3/16/2023* that's why I considered the values from *2/16/2023*.

I thought about comparing the value of each `EAN` in the most recent date with the values from the last 30 days. So, here are the conditions for the query:

1. Filtering the table by the `Logistic` column = US
2. Selecting EANs(rows) whose quantity(value) did not change over the last 30 days from the last `Date` column in the table
3. Skipping over `column S`, which is for the date `3/2/2023`, because it has no data

Can you please help me modify a query in Google sheets to achieve this? This formula below simply won't work because of this column S that has missing values and is included in the last 30 days range. I only want an exception for this particular column.

```
=filter('pivot table'!A3:W;
                'pivot table'!B3:B="US";
                 byrow(filter('pivot table'!C3:W;'pivot table'!C2:W2>max('pivot table'!C2:W2)-30);lambda(Σ;if(counta(Σ)=0;;and(countunique(Σ)=1;eq(counta(Σ);columns(Σ)))))))
```

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with demo data maybe and desired output (manually entered) so that it gives a clear picture & also makes it easy for us to work it out...

Comment: ? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example (a sample demo sheet will help more than an image) that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: @rockinfreakshow  
I edited my question, please review it

Comment: @GiselleValladares TY, I'll keep in mind that. I added the demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added formula to your `output tab`:

```
=filter('pivot table'!A3:V;
                'pivot table'!B3:B="US";
                 byrow(filter('pivot table'!C3:V;'pivot table'!C2:V2>max('pivot table'!C2:V2)-30);lambda(Σ;if(counta(Σ)=0;;and(countunique(Σ)=1;eq(counta(Σ);columns(Σ)))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please look at row 33, I just added one more line, because, in the original table, there are missing values in cells on some dates, which is why the filter doesn't work for them.  What should I do in this case? I want to count blank cells as well, because overall in the last 30 days, the values didn't change

Comment: I've modified the formula in `Cell A20`. you can see how it looks if you wish to consider **blanks+no change in number** as well within the 30-day period.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is exactly what I wanted to get from the query!

Comment: Okay, I've been wrong, I shouldn't have considered blanks. In my original data, I have one column for which there is no data for `US` `Logistic` type and I can't delete it, cause it contains data for other `Logistic` type.  I've added this column S that I want to skip over when filtering, cause it has no data and your first  formula simply won't work because of it. Can you please help me with it, to skip over the column S3:S?

Comment: Updated the formula in output tab `Cell A12`